# Calling c# code from managed c++ crashes

Tags: dll, c++-cli, managed, managed-c++

I have an unmanaged c++ DLL that calls c# code through a managed c++ wrapper. The unmanaged c++ DLL is a plug-in for some application (outside my control). When this application calls the unmanaged c++ DLL everything works fine until the managed c++ code tries to use the c# code. Then it crashes.

I have written a test application that does the same thing as the application, that is, it calls the unmanaged c++ DLL. *This works fine.*

The code is as simple as it could be:

**unmanaged c++:**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void UnmanagedMethodCalledUponByApplication()
{
    new Bridge();
}
```

**managed c++:**

```
Bridge::Brigde()
{
    gcnew Managed(); // This line crashes
}
```

**c#:**

```
public class Managed
{
}
```

I have tried to add a try-catch (...) block around the problematic line but it doesn't catch the error.

If I replace the `gcnew Managed();` line with `MessageBox::Show("Alive!");` it works fine. So my guess is that something is wrong with my c# project settings.

I have tried to compile it with different platforms (Any CPU and x86). I have tried to change target framework. I have tried to call a static method in `Managed` instead of using `gcnew`. Still crashing.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

**Update:**

After advise in comments and answer, I attached the debugger. Now I see that I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` saying that the managed DLL (or one of its dependencies) can't be found.

Here's a guess: The DLLs are placed together, but they are not located in the current directory. The unmanaged c++ DLL is loaded correctly since the main application specifies the path to it. The managed c++ is actually a lib, so that code works fine as well. But when the managed c++ tries to load the c# DLL it looks for it in the wrong directory.

**Update:**

The way to fix this is to load the c# DLL dynamically, using reflection.

Comment: @pivotnig Yes, Bridge is unmanaged.

Comment: Perhaps the host application previously loaded a different version of the .NET runtime (CLR), preventing your code from loading the one it requires.  Using managed code inside plugins is discouraged for this reason, although .NET 4 made some progress with side-by-side loading of multiple versions in the same process.

Comment: Also, catch the exception inside the debugger.

Comment: When you Debug the application and turn on Exceptions--what is the exception you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

Yes, that's a cheap and easy way to get the compiler to generate the required stub that loads and initializes the CLR so it can execute managed code.  Problem is, it doesn't do anything reasonable to deal with exceptions thrown by managed code.  And managed code *likes* throwing exceptions, they are a terrific trouble-shooting tool.  That stops being terrific when there's no way for you to retrieve the exception information.

The best you could possibly do from native code is use the `__try/__except` keywords to catch the managed exception.  Exception code is 0xe0434f4d.  But that still doesn't give you access to the information you need, the exception message and the holy stack trace.

You can debug it.  Project + Properties, Debugging, change the Debugger Type to "Mixed".  Then Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR Exceptions.  The debugger stops when the exception is thrown so you can see what's wrong.

Getting decent diagnostics after you shipped your code requires a better interop mechanism.  Like using COM interop or hosting the CLR yourself.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried debugging (the way you describe), but it won't stop at breakpoints, not even in the unmanaged c++. However, I hadn't tried to attach the debugger since I got this error. Now I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, saying the the managed DLL (or a dependency) can't be found.